# Change string in array using object at index

Tags: string, nsstring, nsarray

So I've created a text file to store small bits of data for my app. Each line is its own object and I am not sure how I can change the string thats at a line. I am trying to write a condition that if the string at a certain line is "YES" and the user changes it to "NO" then it changes the string to "NO". 
Here's an example bit of code

```
if(lineNumber == 0 && userInput == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YES"])
{
    if([[line objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:@"NO"])
    {
       // [[line objectAtIndex:0]... How would you change this to "NO"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have line objectatindex:0 thats kind of like a getter...this should be what you are looking for:

```
[myMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:newObject];
```